# map array of objects, cannot read property 'map' of undefined error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map an array of objects:

```
{"vehicles":[{"id":"xe","modelYear":"k17","url":"/api/vehicle/xe","media":[{"name":"vehicle","url":"/images/xe_k17.jpg"}]},{"id":"xf","modelYear":"k17","url":"/api/vehicle/xf","media":[{"name":"vehicle","url":"/images/xf_k17.jpg"}]},{"id":"xj","modelYear":"k16","url":"/api/vehicle/xj","media":[{"name":"vehicle","url":"/images/xj_k16.jpg"}]},{"id":"fpace","modelYear":"k17","url":"/api/vehicle/fpace","media":[{"name":"vehicle","url":"/images/fpace_k17.jpg"}]},{"id":"ftype","modelYear":"k17","url":"/api/vehicle/ftype","media":[{"name":"vehicle","url":"/images/ftype_k17.jpg"}]}]}
```

However, I get the error:

**Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Here is my map:

```
var vehicleNodes = this.props.data.vehicles.map(function(vehicle){
    return (
      <tr key={vehicle.id}>
        <Td to={`/posts/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.id}</Td>
        <Td to={`/posts/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.name}</Td>
        <Td to={`/posts/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.username}</Td>
        <Td to={`/posts/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.email}</Td>....
```

Comment: So obviously `this.props.data.vehicles` is `undefined`. What is not clear for you? Debug your code, find out why it's undefined. Simple.

Comment: Maybe because `data` is a JSON string, not a JS object ?

Comment: this.props.vehicles.map should work

Comment: Are you calling an api for the vehicle array???